# Error Fail2ban - 24773: error failed during configuration: file contains no section headers

Tags: python, centos

presté bastante atención a la configuración de este archivo, sin embargo recibo este error

[24773:] error failed during configuration: file contains no section headers

Lo entiendo y si comento las líneas que muestra el error funciona, pero no es la idea ya que tiene el tiempo del Ban usando el programa... les dejo el error y hasta la línea que indica la consola.

```
 Starting Fail2Ban Service...
Started Fail2Ban Service.
: 2020-05-21 14:37:49,885 fail2ban                [18887]: ERROR   Failed during configuration: File contains>
file: '/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf', line: 24
'enabled = 48h\n'
2020-05-21 14:37:49,886 fail2ban                [18887]: ERROR   Async configuration of server failed
fail2ban.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Si comento la línea de 48h salta a un error siguiente en sshd

En concreto siguiendo la syntax, el error estaría aquí:

```
#
# [DEFAULT]
bantime = 48h
#
# [sshd]
enabled = true
#
# See jail.conf(5) man page for more information
```

Si alguien puede explicarme si el programa funciona igual simplemente comentando esas lineas y no afecta la funcionalidad le agradezco de antemano!

---

Solucionado hasta la linea gracias, ahora hay otro inconveniente, el servicio no sube y bueno lo habilité normal con systemctl enable fail2ban.service
y systemctl start fail2ban.service

al revisar con systemctl status fail2ban.service el servicio no sube... que podría ser esto?, realmente trato de configurar esto para mitigar ataques Ddos.

Comment: Hola Dante, "file contains no section headers", **tienes comentadas las lineas que marcan la  cabecera de sección**, `[DEFAULT]` y  `[sshd]`. Y no, no funciona igual comentándolas, la primera marca el tiempo de baneo de una IP, el segundo activa la cárcel para OpenSSH, por defecto todas las cárceles están desactivadas.

Comment: Si gracias, lo revisé y tienes razón, no se comentan  pero ahora tengo otro problema :/ ya no sale el error, pero el servicio no sube, debería abrir otra pregunta o puedo hacerlo aquí mismo?

Comment: En mi opinión puedes hacerlo aquí, reformulala si quieres, cambia el título para que refleje tu problema actual. Con lo de antes en realidad debería terminar cerrada ya que es más bien un error tipográfico. Agrega como ejecutas o tratas de ejecutar el servicio, y toda la información que relevante que puedas.

Comment: Bueno, ya le agregué lo ultimo, Rhel 8 parece que cambió varias cosas